# How to indent C function parameters like curly braces and not with cino-(

Tags: indentation

From `:h cino-(`, I see that we can only indent the parameters for the function calls with respect to the opening bracket. This is problematic for functions with long names or within multiple namespaces. For example, with `cino+=(0`, I get this atrocity:

```c
  void Load(int, char**)
  {
    this->connections.push_back(
                                event::Events::ConnectPreRender(
                                                                std::bind(&SystemGUI::Update, this)));
  }
```

I want something sane like this:

```c
    void Load(int /*_argc*/, char ** /*_argv*/)
    {
      this->connections.push_back(
          event::Events::ConnectPreRender(
            std::bind(&SystemGUI::Update, this)));
    }
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the indentation is added from the line with the unclosed parenthesis (not with respect to the opening bracket), and that seems to be the behavior you're seeing in your first example. Maybe something like `(4`  or `(1s` gives a better result in your case.

Comment: @RobertSmith turn that into an answer, please :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Here you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the indentation is added from the line with the unclosed parenthesis (not with respect to the opening bracket), and that seems to be the behavior you're seeing in your first example.

Maybe something like `(4` or `(1s` gives a better result in your case.